# How to find the latest row according to a name?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please help me to sort this issue out. I am sharing a sample sheet in which i need to find out the latest data  according to a specific name. in that sheet i have some details which are assigned to a code. the code of that product won't change but the shop id may change due to the purchase period. so when we enter a code it must go to the data page and select the latest row of that code. for eg : if the code is ABC111 and the data page have 10 ABC111 then it must select the 10th ABC111. the shop id may be differ from the rest 9. but the code must be same.. hope u got what i need.

here is the sheet. please help me to sort this out. thanks in advance - lizi

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BDaQe0-xnfngJjJ8xN8NNvyeF-WvyRn4RFfpRwiWBMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query for this:

`=Query(Query(Data!$A$2:$H, "where F = '"&Input!$B2&"'"), "offset "&countA(QUERY(Data!$F:$F, "where F = '"&Input!$B2&"'"))-1)`

Place the formula above to `A2` and drag onto other cells of `A` as well to apply the same formula

#### Output:

[image: output]

The formula will always get the last matching row from `Data!A2:H` with `Data!F2:F Code` matching to the `Input!B2:B Code`

Comment: am sorry latest code i mean the code from the bottom. if you take a look the sheet again

Comment: Modified the answer and output @Lizi1990

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula({Data!A1:N1; IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(Input!B2:B,Input!B2:B<>""), SORT({Data!F2:F,Data!A2:N},5,0), SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(Data!A:N),2), FALSE))})`

This one formula produces all headers and results.

The outer curly brackets form a virtual array.

The first/top element of that array, `Data!A1:N1`, returns the headers. The semicolon means, "place what follows underneath"; and that will be all of the results.

The center of this formula is a `VLOOKUP`.

The data to look up is a `FILTER` of your `Input!B2:B` values with any blank rows removed.

This data is looked up within a second array: `SORT({Data!F2:F,Data!A2:N},5,0)`. Here, a second virtual array is formed between curly brackets. It consists of a first column containing the CODE-column data, followed by *all* columns (including the CODE-column data again). This simply allows us to search by the CODE data, since `VLOOKUP` searches the leftmost/first column. That virtual array is within a `SORT` that will sort by the data column (virtual column `5`) in reverse order (the '0' parameter at the end of the `SORT`).

As a return result, we want every column but that first tacked-on duplicate of the CODE column (i.e., all of your original Data sheet columns). `SEQUENCE` creates that sequence of column numbers: `1` row of numbers, with as many `COLUMNS` as your original data set (`Data!A:N`), starting at number `2`. (Remember, in the virtual array, your original column 1 has become column 2, and so on, because the added search column of CODEs we placed first became column 1.

`FALSE` simply tells `VLOOKUP` to look for exact matches only.

If a CODE listed in the Input sheet is not found, `IFERROR` will simply return blanks for that row (which will be an indicator to you that the code on the Input sheet for that row was entered incorrectly).

Comment: thanks a lot..  it was really a nice save

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked as you had hoped.

Comment: @eric can u please come over to the sheet again.. as we discussed we need the latest row which contains latest code. here it comes with the latest date. i marked the same product in yellow in the data sheet.  but with different dates. output came with latest date.. the ans must me ABC111-150 but instead it came with ABC111-135. please take a look.

Comment: I changed the SORT clause to sort in descending order by row instead of date. You should be all set (though it is still unclear to me why you'd want the last row, even if that contains an earlier date; but that is up to you).